# How to loop each() 3 times in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

I am making a HTML5 banner and need to loop through 3 overlapping banners.

The script I'm currently using looks like this:

```
var currentDelay; currentDelay = 0;
var pastItem; pastItem = "";

$( ".state" ).each(function() {
    $(this).delay(currentDelay).fadeIn();
    $(this).prev().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    currentDelay += 3000;
});
```

It works, but only works once. .state is the wrapping class for each banner. They are positioned over the top of each other and should fade in and out of each other.

HTML:

```
        <div class="state">
            <img src="images/img-1.jpg" alt="Last minute ski holidays from £299pp" />
            <div class="message"><p>Last minute<br />ski holidays from £299<span>pp</span></p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="state">
            <img src="images/img-2.jpg" alt="Enjoy free skiing guide & coaching" />
            <div class="message blue"><p>Enjoy free<br />skiing guide<br />&amp; coaching</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="state">
            <img src="images/img-3.jpg" alt="Last minute ski holidays from £299pp" />
            <div class="message grey"><p>Limited availability<br /><span class="sub-mes">Don't miss out</span></p></div>
            <p class="call-to-action">Find out more</p>
        </div>
```

Is there a way I can make it loop round 3 times then just stop on the last frame? The last banner needs to fade back to the first frame so it looks seamless.

Big thanks for some help on this :)

Cheers

Rob

Comment: use a setInterval instead of `each` and `delay`. The increment a variable and clear the interval after the desired loop amount has been reached.

Comment: Hi... that's what I was doing initially, but read it's not the right way to go about it?

Comment: Why is it not "the right way"? As long as you store the setInterval in a variable and clear it when done, it should be fine.

Comment: Not sure... just what I read.... Did seem the most logical way to me when I was doing it.... Thanks

Comment: No problem. If you have the link to that article (about set interval), I'd like to read it. The biggest issue with setInterval is memory leaks, just be careful with the variables you create in the interval callback and remember to clear it when done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a self-referencing function that calls its self 3 times.

```
var sleepTimer = 0;

(function LoopyLoo(i) {


  setTimeout(function() {
    var currentDelay = 0
    $(".state").fadeOut();

    $(".state").each(function() {
      $(this).delay(currentDelay).fadeIn();
      currentDelay += 3000;
    });

    if (--i) {
        LoopyLoo(i);
      }//  decrement i and call myLoop again if i > 0
  }, sleepTimer)

  sleepTimer = 9000;

})(3); //Times to call the function.
```

Small change to the css, added some lovely colour so you can see it in action.

```
.state-con {
  position: relative;
}

.state {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.one {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: blue;
}

.three {
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

See it all working with this JS fiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/yojmu6ga/21/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method using `setInterval`.

I have commented the code so I will not bother explaining it.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentDelay; currentDelay = 3000;
    var pastItem; pastItem = "";

    var i=0;

  // interval
  var cycle = setInterval(function() {
      // Fade
      $(".state:eq(" + i + ")").fadeOut();
      // Increment
      i++;
      // Increase delay
      currentDelay+=3000;
      // Check if at last, change to suit wants
      if(i == $(".state").length) {
          /*
          // Loop here
          $(".state").delay(500).fadeIn();
          i=0;
          */
          // Stop interval
          clearInterval(cycle); // Comment this line if looping
      }
   }, currentDelay);

})
```

Fiddle: https: https://jsfiddle.net/4bhv9w80/1/

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works for you:

```
var currentDelay; currentDelay = 0;

$( ".state" ).each(function() {
   var $currentElement =$(this);

   window.setTimeout(function(){
       $( ".state:visible" ).fadeOut();
       $currentElement.fadeIn();
   }, currentDelay);

  currentDelay += 3000    
});

window.setTimeout(function(){
   $( ".state:visible" ).fadeOut();
   $(".state:first").fadeIn();
}, currentDelay);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2k6c1b18/